# Is this past tense or present tense?

Tags: tenses

I still have a problem in distinguishing between past and present tense, especially for these kind of sentences.

> **Added** the device settings menu to override. Developer-related Safari settings when Web inspector **is** connected to an iOS device.

My question is why do we have *added* and *is* in the same sentence?

Comment: The second sentence is incomplete, it doesn't have a verb.

Comment: Are you sure they should be separate sentences? It would make more sense if it said that the menu is used to override developer-related settings.

Comment: Yes, They are separate sentences. I found this when I was reading the release notes from apple. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_release_notes

Comment: There's no period after "override" there.

Comment: If it was like this when you first copied the text, it was probably a typo that has been corrected.

Comment: There's also no subject for the main clause.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't edit the question due to character limitations so refer to the edit below instead.

> Added the device settings menu to override developer-related Safari settings when Web inspector is connected to an iOS device.

The tense here is past with "Added" being the main verb.
In the modifying clause,

> when Web inspector is connected to an iOS device

"is" refers to the state of being connected (inspector and device). This clause is a condition, meaning the statement holds true only when this condition is met. The action of the "settings menu" being added was already done in the past.